# Rename a directory with a filename inside with Python

Tags: python, directory, rename, filenames

I am trying to rename several directories with the name of the first file inside them.

I am trying to:

1. List the files inside a folder.
2. Identify the directories.
3. For each directory, access it, grab the name of the first file inside and rename the directory with such name.

This is what I got so far but it is not working. I know the code is wrong but before fixing the code I would like to know if the logic is right. Can anyone help please?

```
import os

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    print(f'Found directory: {dirpath}')
    dirlist = []
    for d_idx, d in enumerate(dirlist):
        print(d)
    filelist = []
    for f_idex, f in enumerate(filelist):
        files.append(f)[1] 
        print(f)
    os.rename(d, f)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are overwriting the values of what `os.walk('.')` returns. As a first step, instead of `dirs = []` and `files = []`. rename them to someting else like `dirList = []` and `filesList = []`.

Comment: `1st file name` ???

Comment: the name of the first file inside the directory

Comment: I think you shoud specify some kind of ordering criteria, `os` functions order names alphabetically by default

Comment: yes I know, I meant the first file according to os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. You are renaming directories as you iterate them with `os.walk`. This is not a good idea, `os.walk` gives you a generator, meaning it creates elements as you iterate them, so renaming things within the loop will confuse it.
2. Both `for d_idx, d in enumerate(dirlist):` and `for f_idex, f in enumerate(filelist):` iterate over variables that are declared to be empty lists in the line before, so those loops don't do anything. Also, within the second one, `files.append(f)` would append `f` to the list `files`, but the `[1]` at the end means "get the second element (remeber Python indexing is 0-based) of the value returned by the `append` function" - but `append` does not return anything (it modifies the list, not returns a new list), so that would fail (and you are not using the value read by `[1]` anyway, so it would not do anything).
3. In `os.rename(d, f)`, first, since the loops before do not ever run, `d` and `f` will not have a value, but also, assuming both `d` and `f` came from `dirs` and `files`, they would be given as paths relative to their parents, not to your current directory (`.`), so the renaming would fail.

This code should work as you want:

```py
import os

# List of paths to rename
renames = []
# Walk current dir
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    # Skip this dir (cannot rename current directory)
    if root == '.': continue
    # Add renaming to list
    renames.append((root, files[0]))
# Iterate renaming list in reverse order so deepest dirs are renamed first
for root, new_name in reversed(renames):
    # Make new full dir name (relative to current directory)
    new_full_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(root), new_name)
    # Rename
    os.rename(root, new_full_name)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. It works perfectly. And thank you for taking the time to explain the code in such detail.